# Java streams - Map<key, List<VO>> to Map<key, List<String from VO>

Tags: java, java-stream

I've a `Map<KeyString, List<MyVO>>`.

**MyVO.java** contains:

```
String name;
int id;
```

I want to map it into `Map<KeyString, List<names from MyVO>`.

How can achieve this using java 8 streams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> response =
        map.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey, 
                        e -> e.getValue().stream()
                                .map(MyVO::getName)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a record to demo.  A class would also work here.

```
record VO(String getStr) 
}
```

first create some data

```
Map<String, List<VO>> map =
        Map.of("A", List.of(new VO("S1"), new VO("S2")), "B",
                List.of(new VO("S3"), new VO("S4")));
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
A=[VO[str=S1], VO[str=S2]]
B=[VO[str=S3], VO[str=S4]]
```

- now stream the entry set of the original map
- and collect using `Collectors.toMap`.
- use the orginal key from the `Entry`.
- and stream the list of VO to pull out the string and create a new list.

```
Map<String,List<String>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Entry::getKey,
            e -> e.getValue().stream().map(VO::getStr).toList()));
```

prints

```
A=[S1, S2]
B=[S3, S4]
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution:

```
public static void mapNames() {
    final Map<String, List<MyVO>> voMap = new HashMap<>();
    voMap.put("all", Arrays.asList(
            new MyVO(1, "John"),
            new MyVO(2, "Bill"),
            new MyVO(3, "Johanna")
    ));

    final Map<String, List<String>> nameMap = voMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            Map.Entry::getKey,
                            e -> e.getValue().stream()
                                    .map(MyVO::getName)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            ));

    System.out.println(nameMap);
}
```

Output:

```
{all=[John, Bill, Johanna]}
```